# Remove rows within a group if conditions of another row are met

Tags: r

I've got a data frame `df` (+/- 331000 observations with 4 variables) with `Date` (range in format = "%Y-%m-%d"), `ID` (factor with 19 levels), `Station` (factor with 18 levels), and `Presence` (`1/0`). 
The data frame is setup in such a way that there's a range of dates (over an almost three year period) for each `ID` at each `Station`, and whether a person was present (`1/0`) on a particular day at a particular Station.

If one would subset/filter the df according to a day and ID, you'd get the following dataset (I'll refer to this from now on as 'group'):

> ```
> filter(df, Date == "2016-01-03" & ID == "Fred")
> ```

```
 Date           ID     Station       Presence
 <date>         <fct>  <fct>         <dbl>
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station1      0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station2      0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station3      0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station4      1
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station5      0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station6      0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station7      0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station8      0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station9      0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station10     0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station11     0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station12     0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station13     0
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station14     0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station15     0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station16     0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station17     0 
 2016-01-03     Fred   Station18     0
```

I would like to remove rows from the group if the following conditions are met: 
For each group, if `df$Presence == 1`, remove rows with `df$Presence == 0` (it is possible to have rows with multiple `df$Presence == 1` within one group, e.g. Fred was at Station4, Station9 and Station 15 on 2016-01-06). But if there are no rows with `df$Presence == 1` within the group, don't remove any of the rows (so I can't simply remove all the `df$Presence == 0` rows).

The above group would thus become:

```
 Date         ID      Station    Presence
 <date>       <fct>   <fct>      <dbl>
 2016-01-03   Fred    Station4   1
```

However, the following group would stay as it is (as there are no `Presence == 1` within the group):

> ```
> filter(df, Date== "2016-01-03" & ID == "Mark")
> ```

```
 Date       ID    Station    Presence
 <date>     <fct> <fct>      <dbl>
 2016-01-03 Mark Station1    0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station2    0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station3    0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station4    0
 2016-01-03 Mark Station5    0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station6    0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station7    0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station8    0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station9    0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station10   0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station11   0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station12   0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station13   0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station14   0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station15   0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station16   0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station17   0 
 2016-01-03 Mark Station18   0
```

I've thought of starting with

> ```
> df %>%
>   group_by(Date, ID) %>%
> ```

However, I don't know how to proceed from there. I don't know how to deal with the contrasting conditions.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Make a smaller dataset we can copy/paste into R to test.You probably just need a group_by and an `any(Presence==1) & (Presence==0)` to remove the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
dat%>%
   group_by(Date,ID)%>%
   filter(all(Presence==0)|Presence==1)

# A tibble: 19 x 4
# Groups:   Date, ID [2]
   Date       ID    Station   Presence
   <chr>      <chr> <chr>        <int>
 1 2016-01-03 Fred  Station4         1
 2 2016-01-03 Mark  Station1         0
 3 2016-01-03 Mark  Station2         0
 4 2016-01-03 Mark  Station3         0
 5 2016-01-03 Mark  Station4         0
 6 2016-01-03 Mark  Station5         0
 7 2016-01-03 Mark  Station6         0
 8 2016-01-03 Mark  Station7         0
 9 2016-01-03 Mark  Station8         0
10 2016-01-03 Mark  Station9         0
11 2016-01-03 Mark  Station10        0
12 2016-01-03 Mark  Station11        0
13 2016-01-03 Mark  Station12        0
14 2016-01-03 Mark  Station13        0
15 2016-01-03 Mark  Station14        0
16 2016-01-03 Mark  Station15        0
17 2016-01-03 Mark  Station16        0
18 2016-01-03 Mark  Station17        0
19 2016-01-03 Mark  Station18        0
```